# How to get the first digit of a uint256

Tags: solidity, uint256

I want to check, if the first digit of a uint256 is equal 5.

I therefore do the following:

```
function _numDigits(uint256 _number) internal pure returns (uint8) {
  uint256 number = _number;
  uint8 digits = 0;
  while (number != 0) {
      number /= 10;
      digits++;
  }
  return digits;
}

function firstDigitIsFive(uint256 _number) external pure returns (bool) {
    uint256 numdigits = _numDigits(_number);
    if(numdigits == 1) {
        return _number == 5;
    } else {
        return _number/10**(numdigits-1) == 5;
    }
}
```

Is there a better, easier and cheaper way to evaluate the first digit of an uint256?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitute `x` for whichever number you want to check for.

```
function highestOrderDigitIsX(uint256 number, uint256 x) public pure returns (bool) { 
    while (number >= 10) {
        number /= 10;
    }
    
    return number == x;
}
```

For completeness:

```
function lowestOrderDigitIsX(uint256 number, uint256 x) public pure returns (bool) {
    return number % 10 == x;
}
```